# PN532 emulated card not read by an iphone but can with Android

Tags: arduino, android-emulator, nfc, pn532

I am using the PN532 as an emulator using the `emulate_tag_ndef.ino` example from arduino. I updated the emulate library according to another post ([PN532 emulated card not read by an Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702411/pn532-emulated-card-not-read-by-an-android-phone)) to make it work, but it only works with Android. With iPhones I can only send up to 47 bytes, if succeeded.
Here's how I set the PN532_COMMAND_TGINITASTARGET command:

```
uint8_t command[] = {
      PN532_COMMAND_TGINITASTARGET,
      0x05,                  // MODE: 0x04 = PICC only, 0x01 = Passive only (0x02 = DEP only)

      // MIFARE PARAMS
      0x04, 0x00,         // SENS_RES (seeeds studio set it to 0x04, nxp to 0x08)
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // NFCID1t    (is set over sketch with setUID())
      0x20,               // SEL_RES    (0x20=Mifare DelFire, 0x60=custom)

      // FELICA PARAMS
      0x01, 0xFE,         // NFCID2t (8 bytes) https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532/blob/master/Adafruit_PN532.cpp FeliCa NEEDS TO BEGIN WITH 0x01 0xFE!
      0x05, 0x01, 0x86,
      0x04, 0x02, 0x02,
      0x03, 0x00,         // PAD (8 bytes)
      0x4B, 0x02, 0x4F, 
      0x49, 0x8A, 0x00,   
      0xFF, 0xFF,         // System code (2 bytes)

      0x01, 0x01, 0x66,   // NFCID3t (10 bytes)
      0x6D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x10,
      0x02, 0x00, 0x00,

      0x00, // length of general bytes
      0x00  // length of historical bytes
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make the iPhone write to the PN532? I am using the NFC Tools app to write to it. I have tried other apps but without any luck